# Novel polymorphism - any reasons for this code?

Tags: c#, object-oriented-design, polymorphism

As part of my work on a legacy C# application I've come across a novel (to me) use of an interface & concrete implementations.  I can't think of any reason why you'd do the following, but I'm pretty thick, so maybe someone else can?

```
public interface IContract
{
    ContractImplementation1 Contract { get; }
    bool IsCollection { get; }
    bool Touched { get; set; }
}

public class ContractImplementation1 : IContract
{
    public ContractImplementation1(string propertyOne, string propertyTwo, string propertyThree, string propertyFour)
    {
        PropertyOne = propertyOne;
        PropertyTwo = propertyTwo;
        PropertyThree = propertyThree;
        PropertyFour = propertyFour;
    }

    public ContractImplementation1 Contract { get { return this; } }
    public bool IsCollection { get { return false; } }
    public bool Touched { get; set; }

    public string PropertyOne { get; private set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; private set; }
    public string PropertyThree { get; private set; }
    public string PropertyFour { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyFour))
            return string.Format("{0} => {1}: {2}", PropertyOne, PropertyTwo, PropertyThree);
        else
            return string.Format("{0} => {1}: {2} {3}", PropertyOne, PropertyTwo, PropertyThree, PropertyFour);
    }

}

public class ContractImplementation2 : IContract
{
    public ContractImplementation1 Contract { get { return null; } }
    public bool IsCollection { get { return true; } }
    public bool Touched { get; set; }

    public List<ContractImplementation1> Contracts = new List<ContractImplementation1>();
}
```

I can't get my head around the super-type having a property that is a sub-type of itself.
Following Cosmin's answer: I can't get my head around why you'd have the sub-type as a property given that the property returns itself on the implementation (rather than a 'parent' of the same type i.e. a different instantiation of the super-type).

Comment: Polymorphic code is best understood from code that uses this polymorphic code. You didn't post any.

Comment: What do you consider the super-type and sub-type in this example? It looks like two classes with similar names that both implement the same Interface and one class references another class.

Comment: the classes are both sub-types of the interface.  The interface is the super-type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classes you've shown are implementations of nodes in some kind of tree structure.  The `IsCollection` property determines if this is a leaf node or a branch(?) node.  If `IsCollection` is true, then there is no "data" at this node, so you have to continue down the tree.  If `IsCollection` is false, then this is a leaf node, so it's valid to look at the `Contract` property.

The domain model seems to indicate that a contract can be made up of other contracts, and so on.

The most likely reason for it being the way it is, is because originally we just had `ContractImplementation1`, and then they realized that contracts could be nested like this.  So someone created the `IContract` interface for the generic node-in-a-tree (and really should have named it `IContractNode` or something) and then created `ContractImplementation2` to be the branch.  This wasn't really the right way to do it.  The right way would be more like:

```
interface IContractNode 
{
    bool IsLeaf { get; }
    // Only access this is IsLeaf is true
    Contract Contract { get; }
    // Only access this if IsLeaf is false
    ReadOnlyCollection<IContractNode> Children { get; }
}

class ContractNodeLeaf : IContractNode 
{
    public ContractNodeLeaf(Contract contract)
    {
        if(contract == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("contract");
        this.Contract = contract;
    }
    public bool IsLeaf { get { return true; } }
    public Contract Contract { get; private set; } 
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IContractNode> Children 
        { get { return new List<IContractNode>().AsReadOnly(); }
}

class ContractNodeBranch : IContractNode 
{
    public ContractNodeBranch(ReadOnlyCollection<IContractNode> children)
    {
        if(children== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("children");
        this.Children= children;
    }
    public bool IsLeaf { get { return false; } }
    public Contract Contract 
        { get { throw new InvalidOperationException("I'm not a leaf!"); } 
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IContractNode> Children { get; private set;}
}
```

... where `Contract` is the original class, from before the change.

Comment: And just to make it clear, the inheritance was wrong and the OP suspicion, right: less specific classes should have no knowledge of more specific ones.

Answer (score 9):

> I can't get my head around the super-type having a property that is a sub-type of itself.

The code you posted, with `PropertyOne`, `PropertyTwo` ... `PropertyFour` is probably just an example, so I'll assume the liberty to provide my own example of a case where the super-type having properties that are sub-types of itself makes obvious sense:

Let's say you've got a class `Human` with subclass `Male` and subclass `Female`. If you'd add the properties `Mother` and `Father` to `Human`, it makes sense for them to be of the sub-type `Female` and `Male`.

Given this example, the generic answer is: if the super-type and the sub-type have enough in common, why not? I can imagine this sort of situation arising quite often in tree-like structures.

Comment: That makes sense and I see why you'd have that sort of structure in a tree.  However in the example code that's not the case - the subtypes either return themselves, or nothing, not a step back down the tree.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a (poorly done) implementation of the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).  Its primary purpose is to allow you to treat an object the same as a collection of those objects, without having to differentiate between the two everywhere in the calling code.  I say poorly done because when properly used you shouldn't need the `IsCollection` property.

This happens to be a highly useful and common pattern with trees.  You can call methods on a node without worrying about if it is a leaf or contains a whole subtree.